# how to deploy the next js 13 app on iis server 10

Tags: node.js, next.js, iis-10

1. Configure the `iisnode` and rewrite.
2. Deploy the next.js app on iis 10

A lot of articles explain different things. First, do we need to configure `iisnode` and rewrite?

web.config configurations also different.

I tried a lot of time and came up with this error.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdxta.png)

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs You just need a few simple steps. Simpler than answers below.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow below steps to host the next js app on iis.

1. Install latest Node version , iis node module , url rewrite module

2)Add this code in web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;E:\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />

  </system.webServer>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Set the path according to your machine file location.

Make sure to run `npm run build` command

Comment: i have set the path="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\New\server.js" correct 
after that this error came 

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Error Code    0x80070021

Config Error    This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*****\web.config

Comment: @ErandaKuruneru. 1)open iis server, select server name from the connection pane. 2)from middle pane select configuration editor 3)from the section drop down select "system.webServer/handlers" 4)From action pane click unlock section. [image](https://imgur.com/pueu2DC)

Comment: You missed the contents of `server.js`.

Answer (score -1):

**Configure IIS:**

Open the IIS Manager on your server.

Create a new site or select an existing site.

In the site settings,
navigate to "Handler Mappings."

Add a new module mapping with the following settings:

- Request path: *
- Module: iisnode
- Executable: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
- Arguments: %iisnode.dll%

**Deploy Next.js App:**

Copy the contents of the Next.js app's out directory (created during the build) to the directory where your IIS site is configured to serve files.
Configure web.config:

Create a web.config file in the root of your Next.js app (next to your package.json). This file contains IIS configuration settings.

**Sample web.config:**

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="nodejs">
      <match url="/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
<iisnode loggingEnabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You missed the contents of `server.js`.