# HTTP Error 500.1000 - Internal Server Error

Tags: node.js, iis, next.js, deployment, iisnode

Im trying to deploy next js on windows server 2019 and facing this issue, i have installed iisnode, urlwrite and everything needed. Node is working fine. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8Og6.png)

I have tried reinstalling iisnode, restarting pc. Changing node version.

And the thing is in my another server its deploying fine like when i add a website in IIS it creates IISModules folder but in this new server its not happening i think thats the issue but i tried everything i could do to fix that but sadly not working.

Comment: could you follow this steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/77781108/11147346 and also assign the permission to the node and iis site root folder path for iis_iusrs and iusr

Comment: Next.js authors do not have an official post on how to deploy on IIS, so “everything needed” is unknown at this moment. You’d better use a Linux machine and follow the necessary steps there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: IISNode issues are not easy to troubleshoot and it is also out-of-maintenance for years. Switch to HttpPlatformHandler, and you just need a few simple steps, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs